# How to ignore special characters(" ' , - \ / etc) while data insert

Tags: php, mysql

I storing articles in database that contains special characters like `"`, `'`, etc. but it gives error while saving in MySQL:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's and Moral Science's books in school. I clearly remember the picture of a Hindu' at line 1

Comment: I have used `mysql_real_escape_string` but now it give following error   

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\admin\newArticle.php on line 48

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\admin\newArticle.php on line 48

Answer (score 3):

[`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) everything you put into a query. Always. No exceptions.

Alternatively, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: I have used `mysql_real_escape_string` but now it give following error   

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\admin\newArticle.php on line 48

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\admin\newArticle.php on line 48

Comment: @amanda You need to `mysql_real_escape_string` *after* you have established a connection to the database, that's probably your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: I have used `mysql_real_escape_string` but now it gives following error   

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\admin\newArticle.php on line 48

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\xampp\htdocs\shizin\admin\newArticle.php on line 48

Comment: he cant open the connection, the user or password wrong, no permission to this user ...